# How do you produce a nice table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am new to **R** and R markdown, and was wondering how to make a nice table in an html file. I am trying to use `ascii`, but when I enter the code below I get a table that looks okay in an **R** console window, but looks bad in the html. I am pretty sure that the table is too wide, but I am not sure, it is 15 columns of 11 obs. Any help would be appreciated and I can add more information if I am not being clear.

```
print(ascii(FINALTABLE), type = "org", include.colnames = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think you need some css

Comment: `type = "org"` is for emacs org-mode are your sure that is really what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `pander` package to produce `Rmarkdown` compatible tables:

```
> library(pander)
> pandoc.table(head(iris[, 1:3]), style="rmarkdown")


|  Sepal.Length  |  Sepal.Width  |  Petal.Length  |
|:--------------:|:-------------:|:--------------:|
|      5.1       |      3.5      |      1.4       |
|      4.9       |       3       |      1.4       |
|      4.7       |      3.2      |      1.3       |
|      4.6       |      3.1      |      1.5       |
|       5        |      3.6      |      1.4       |
|      5.4       |      3.9      |      1.7       |
```

Comment: Or set that option only once with `panderOptions('table.style', 'rmarkdown')` and than call simply `pander` for the R objects, e.g. `pander(head(iris[, 1:3]))`, to save some key presses :)

Comment: And for converting the RMarkdown file to html, use the chunk option `results = "asis"` to correctly render the table.